# Import Multiple Named Worksheets from Multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to import multiple worksheets from different workbooks, for different scenarios. To explain better - I have scenario Apple, Banana, and Cherry. Each scenario has it's own file folder with workbooks One, Two, and, Three. Workbook one has sheets Jack, John, and Jill. Workbook Two has sheets Rachel, Robin, and Ryan. Workbook Three has sheets Sam, Sally, and Susan. The sheet names don't change from scenario to scenario.

The master workbook has a drop-down of the different scenarios and a list of the sheets to bring in from each workbook (e.g. drop-down selected is scenario Apple, ranges include - from workbook One import Jack and Jill, from workbook Two import Robin, and from workbook Three import Sam and Susan).

See image for masterworkbook layout:
[image: See image for masterworkbook layout]

The code needs to go to the appropriate scenario folder (referred to as Run in the code) and then open up each workbook and pull in the appropriate worksheets. Right now I am getting

> Run-time error 9: subscript out of range

on the `Workbooks(Masterbook)=Workbooks(Databook)` line.

Am I over complicating this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub CopySheetsfromCRSS()

Dim MasterBook As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim DataBook As String
Dim CurrentPullSheet As String
Dim DataDumpSheet As String
Dim PasteSheet As String
Dim OneRange As Range
Dim TwoRange As Range
Dim ThreeRange As Range
Dim TypesOfData As Range
Dim CopyRange As String
Dim Locations As Range
Set OneRange = Range("B1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
Set TwoRange = Range("C1", Range("C1").End(xlDown))
Set ThreeRange = Range("D1", Range("D1").End(xlDown))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Read in Range of Copy Data'
Let CopyRange = "A1:DI517"
'Read range of sheets to Pull'
Set TypesOfData = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))

MasterBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
'Type of Data Loop'
For i = 1 To TypesOfData.Rows.Count
    If i = 1 Then
        'One'
        Set Locations = OneRange
        ElseIf i = 2 Then
        'Two'
        Set Locations = TwoRange
        Else
        'Three'
        Set Locations = ThreeRange
    End If

'Run Loop'
    For j = 1 To Rows.Count
        If j = 1 Then
        RunCell = "E1"
        End If
        CurrentRun = .Range(RunCell).Value
        'Open Workbook'
        Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Runs\" & CurrentRun & "\" & CurrentRun & "_" & TypesOfData.Cells(i, 1) & ".xlsx"
        DataBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
            For k = 1 To Locations.Rows.Count
                'Copy Data'
                CurrentPullSheet = Locations.Cells(k, 1)
                PasteSheet = "Data_" & CurrentPullSheet
                Workbooks(MasterBook).Sheets(PasteSheet).Range(CopyRange).Value = Workbooks(DataBook).Sheets(CurrentPullSheet).Range(CopyRange).Value
            Next
        'Close Workbook'
        Workbooks(MasterBook).Activate
        For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
            If Not Not wb.Name <> ActivateWorkbook.Name Then
            If wb.Name Like "*.xls" Then
                wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
                Else
                wb.Close
            End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That error implies that 1 or more of the following is true: `Workbooks(MasterBook)` is nothing... `.Sheets(PasteSheet)` is nothing... `Workbooks(DataBook)` is nothing... `.Sheets(CurrentPullSheet)` is nothing. It would make it easier on you to set your workbooks to an object variable as well as your worksheets.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a better answer for you, but honestly a database would be much better for this kind of task.  Look into getting Access or SQL Server setup.  That will make things like this much, much, much easier.  You can do what you want, but it's going to be very difficult to setup using VBA, and it's going to be a nightmare to maintain.  You should try to use the best tool for the job, and in this case it is NOT Excel.